# code blocks with 4 spaces not working

Tags: support, markdown

When creating a question it is not interpreting code blocks correctly when you indent with 4 spaces.
For example:

```
This should be code!
```

But it is not.

EDIT: must have a blank line before and after block code, maybe specify this in instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an empty line before and after the code block. Otherwise the line break is ignored by Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me :

```
<?php echo "this is a code block"; ?>
```