# Difference between <blockquote> and markdown’s >

Tags: support, markdown

I always thought the markdown `>` was a shortcut for HTML’s `<blockquote>`. However, there appears to be differences. Compare this …

```
> This is `monospace` markdown
```

> This is `monospace` markdown

With this …

```
<blockquote>This is `monospace` markdown</blockquote>
```

> This is `monospace` markdown

I would think this would be the same and I find this confusing, especially for new users who aren’t used to Markdown yet.

Is this difference intentionally?

---

Oh, and this isn't a solution...

```
<blockquote>This is <pre>monospace</pre> markdown</blockquote>
```

> This is
>
> ```
> monospace
> ```
>
> markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown is normally not converted when located within block-level HTML elements. It's a mild annoyance at times. Some extended versions of Markdown provide some utility for making this work; for example, [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr) adds this ability by checking for a `markdown` attribute on the containing block HTML:

```
<div markdown="1">
This is *true* markdown text.
</div>
```

...and then renders the Markdown followed by removing the attribute on the container.

Apparently StackExchange does not use any similar functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<code>`, not `<pre>` when you want to show code in a HTML blockquote.

```
<blockquote>This is <code>monospace</code> markdown</blockquote>
```

> This is `monospace` markdown

But why would you? The regular [Markdown](http://labs.toscho.de/sidebar/markdown.html) does what you need in this case.

Maybe related: [code blocks with 4 spaces not working](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/code-blocks-with-4-spaces-not-working)

Comment: Okay, that solves the problem. But still, I consider it to be very weird that the markdown doesn't work in a blockquote. Is it meant to be this way? I had to edit a question of a quite new user today because that didn't work, so that shows this is confusing for new users.

Comment: Markdown converters are usually not real parsers, just a bunch of weird regular expressions. Mixing those with another parser (HTML) will always result in strange edge cases. I think that’s inevitable. We have to live with it.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for your support!